# what is the difference between Button button=(Button) findViewbyID(R.id.button); and Button button = new Button; in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

What is the difference between `Button button= (Button) findViewbyID(R.id.button);` and `Button button = new Button(this);`?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int) vs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View(android.content.Context)

Comment: After setContentView you must use findViewById to get it. new Button is constructor and creates a new instance of button. I don't recommend this. The better way is to create button in layout and get id using findViewById.

Comment: `findViewById()` finds the view within the view group by its ID. `new Button(context)` creates a new button that must also be added to a viewgroup.

Comment: In simple language, findViewById use for bind the button which is in xml file. The new Button() use for create the new button run time.

Comment: @PatidarNikunj see my answer. Might be it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approach to create and set `button`.

1. By using xml file:

In your `activity.xml` you will write code like this:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press" />
```

Then you have to set it's reference in `activity class` file like this:

```
    Button button=(Button) findViewbyID(R.id.button);
```

2. Programatically inside Activity class like:

   ```
   Button myButton = new Button(this);
   myButton.setText("Press");
   LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
   LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   layout .addView(myButton, lp );
   ```

Comment: Down voters do comment also why you are down voting.

Answer (score 1):

`new Button` you're just creating a button on your application memory (RAM memory). This button is not on the screen and it's not inside any layout until you call `addView(buton)` somewhere.

`findViewById` you're just FINDING and getting the reference of a view that have already been created and that is already in the layout and that will be drawn to the screen during drawn operation.

Comment: Thnx Perfectly understand